# Parsing a Flex Application Object Hierarchy Using FunFX

Tags: testing, apache-flex, automation

I'm attempting to test a Flex application in which Objects do not have static IDs. I'd like to use FunFX for automation, since it can easily be kicked off from a Linux shell.

This said, FunFX doesn't appear to contain functions which allow users to access children via their parent objects (e.g. `parent.get_child_at(<index>)` or `parent.children()` for iteration). I see methods which return the *number* of children beneath a parent, but I don't see any iteration functionality which would allow me to parse the hierarchical structure.

Has anyone used FunFX to test a black-box Flex app where object IDs are not known? If so, how did you accomplish accessing the various objects & components to drive their functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FunFX includes the [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/) tool which allows you to peek at component IDs, hierarchies, etc. But, unstable component IDs are ( obviously ) a setback to having robust tests. However, FunFX does allow driving of components from "automation name", "automation value" and index. So, there is some hope. :)

Comment: Wow, an answer after such a long time -- thanks!  I'm not doing testing any longer, but I appreciate the response.